# Java awt.Robot not working inside a virtual machine?

Tags: java, virtual-machine, awtrobot

I'm trying to use the java.awt.Robot class for testing inside a virtual machine. Everything works as expected if I test it in my host computer, but when I run the same program inside a virtual machine, nothing happens and there is no error/exceptions. I have tried inside virtual machines running Windows XP or Windows 7 on different computers and it never worked.

The code I used for testing on the machines was very simple:

```
try 
{
    final Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(500, 500);
} 
catch (AWTException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run this, the program just ends and the mouse doesn't move. Is the robot class not working in virtual machines? If it doesn't, is there another way to simulate mouse movement/clicks? Have you ever tried to use this class in a virtual machine and if it worked, what was your setup?

Comment: there's nothing in a VM that will be different, given you have the proper java installed, etc. A VM, by it's nature, doesn't know it's a VM (usually, at least with most Windows versions the VM doesn't know it's a VM). Most Windows VM's run in HVM mode, meaning they think they are running on bare metal. So, I'd wager, you have something else that's wrong in your setup.

Comment: give http://www.codoid.com/products/view/2/27 a try

Comment: @Leo the OP shouldn't need something like that to get it to work. It's obvious his VM is not setup properly. This is more or less a question that probably should be on SuperUser or ServerFault. Java, and AWT, by nature, will run about the same on any system given Java is setup properly. With a VM, the OP needs to make sure he has the vm's tools/drivers installed properly, and the screen resolution is larger than the 500x500 he's trying to move the mouse in.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, after some more testing I finally found out what the problem was. The program actually works in the VM, we just don't see the mouse cursor moving. (If I mouseMove to a button's coordinate and then simulate a mouse press, we can see the button getting pressed but the cursor stays at its original position.)

Answer (score 0):

IT won't work... similar problem we faced ... when you opened your VM on your laptop/desktop that time your test script will pass.

Try this... Start your test and close the VNC/RDC  and then later on check your results it will (fail).

Reason is ... this Robot class is looking for the physical keyboard to be present however when we run the test suite on CI, there we don't have physical keyboard ...

So it wont work.

Alternative solution:  Use Selenium methods

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it does not work because you have installed inside your machine **Guest Additions**. I was using VirtualBox and when I uninstalled my Guest Additions program (inside the virtual machine control panel), the problem was solved and my mouse could move just like the tests I did on my host machine. I hope it helps you. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and easily fixed it. Go to the input settings of the virtual machine and disable mouse integration. This will change your pointer to the one inside the virtual machine. The Robot mouse functions should work again, but the mouse might have a bit of input lag, as your real mouse will have pass signals into the VM.