# Why can't I close popups or dialog boxes with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

**Summary:** In the url below, please click the reply button. Then, a popup will appear and hide the reply button. When you click a blank area or on the paragraph containing 'post id:', the popup disappears and you can see the reply button again. I want to do these things using the code below.

**Problem:** None of the last 3 method calls in main make the popup disappear. What is wrong with my code and how do I make it work ?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Temp {
    private static final WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();

    private static String reply_btn_xpath = "//button[contains(concat(\" \", normalize-space(@class), \" \"), \" "
            + "reply_button" + " \")]";
    private static By reply_btn_loc = By.xpath(reply_btn_xpath);

    private static String url = "https://sfbay.craigslist.org/pen/apa/5764613878.html";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        browser.get(url);
        WebElement reply = browser.findElement(reply_btn_loc);
        reply.click();
        WebElement post_id = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(., 'post id:')]"));
        post_id.click();
        click_with_actions(post_id);
        click_with_js(post_id);
    }

    public static void click_with_actions(WebElement element) {
        Actions actions = new Actions(browser);
        actions.moveToElement(element).click().perform();
    }

    public static void click_with_js(WebElement element) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) browser).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
    }

}
```

Apparently, it is advised not to use java.awt.Robot in VMs or CI to do the clicks because they don't have real keyboards. [Java awt.Robot not working inside a virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485769/java-awt-robot-not-working-inside-a-virtual-machine)

I tried Robot also in the above code and it did not work.

```
public static void click_with_robot(WebElement element, int x, int y) {
    Robot bot = null;
    try {
        bot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Point location = element.getLocation();

    int x_loc = location.getX() + x;
    int y_loc = location.getY() + y;

    bot.mouseMove(x_loc, y_loc);

    bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you choose this paragraph to close pop-up? can you try to use, for example, `//p[@id="display-date"]` instead? Also specify exception log if any exist

Comment: @Andersson - Actually, I want to click on any text/blank area outside the popup so that it will close. That is why I chose post id. I tried your xpath and .click(). It did not work.

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: @Andersson - No exception and nothing happens.

Comment: hm... Both options works for me. What is your `Chrome` and `chromedriver` versions?

Comment: @Andersson - Chrome is 52.0.2743.116 m and updating now. How do I get the version of chromedriver ?

Comment: You can start it from `cmd` (enter `chromedriver` and click `Enter`) to see current version

Comment: @Andersson - Thanks. v2.9.248315.

Comment: These are exact the same versions I use... As last resort you can use `browser.refresh()` to get rid of pop-up

Comment: @Andersson - Yes. I thought about it. But, I don't want to do it that way. Its an unnecessary page load. Imagine if the page is heavy and you have to do this 100s of times.

Comment: In that case you can look toward `Javascript` that allow to make pop-up invisible with `visibility="hidden"` attribute. I know how to do this in `Python`, but unfortunatelly I'm not familiar with `Java` syntax...