# Why does my Robot Screenshot method capture a black screen?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

1. I have literally attempted to alter the code in many ways but im still having no luck.
2. Currently running all tests using google chrome and windows server 2008 (Virtual machine).
3. My code:

   ```
           Robot robot = new Robot();
       //capture a screenshot of desktop size
       Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
       BufferedImage capture = robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);

       //save to file
       ImageIO.write(capture, "bmp", new File(image12345 + ".jpg")));
   ```
4. The following code works, but i need a capture of the entire screen including URL:

   ```
           File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) BrowserFactory.getDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

       FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile,
               new File((test12345 + ".jpeg")));
   ```

Any ideas why this is happenening?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium WebDriver does not allows you to take an snapshot of the browser including the navigation bar. As you notice, it only captures the content of the page. Therefore, you need to use something like Java Robot to made it.

The code snippets you provided are correct. You can find another working examples [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/ScreenshotTest.java) and [here](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/test/FullScreenshotTest.java).

Comment: thanks for the useful links, would you know why the RobotClass takes a black screenshot when running a test on a virtual machine? 

Thanks again

Comment: It seems it works in local but not in a virtual environment, sorry (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485769/java-awt-robot-not-working-inside-a-virtual-machine)).

Comment: Garcia thats exactly the problem, thanks for your help